# n-dimensional vector space isomorphic to the n-th product of a field as abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space (of dimension n) over a field $F$. I need to show that $V$ is isomorphic to $F^n$ as abelian groups. However, I don't really understand what does "isomorphic as abelian groups" mean, my (poor) attempt to solve this was:

Let $f:V\to F^n$, $f((v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)):=v_1+\ldots+v_n$, clearly $f$ is a group homomorphism, but it is not biyective since, for example, in the case where $dim(V)=2$ and $F=\mathbb{R}$ we have $f((2,-2))=0=f((3,-3))$, I've also tried it by defining $f$ to be the product of a vector's entries but obviously it didn't work so I'm stuck!

I think this should be an easy problem but since I don't quite understand it, it's giving me problems. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The image of this function is not in $F^n$

Comment: Are you aware that any vector space of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $F^n$? "As abelian groups" means that you ignore scalar multiplication and just look at addition.

Comment: I think that you meant to ask about finite dimensional (as opposed to finite) vector spaces, so I edited the question accordingly. Do roll back, if I misunderstood. The only finite vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is the 0-dimensional space, and I doubt the question wanted you to concentrate on that. Over finite fields there would be other finite vector spaces, but it sounds like you are not restriced to a finite $F$ (and the result holds for all fields anyway).

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. You should change whichever is wrong.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I'm translating the question to English and I might have done so incorrectly. It does make more sense for $V$ to be finite dimensional.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Sorry, I don't see where is the mistake, could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Amr I was thinking of $F^n$ as the direct sum of $F$ rather than direct product in my first attempt, then my function is well-defined, no? It's of no use though.

Comment: @Zero: In your title you speak of a vector space being isomorphic to a field, in your question you speak of it being isomorphic to $F^n$, where $F$ is a field.

Comment: @ChrisEagle would you be able to take a look at this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374069/generalization-of-n-th-dimensional-vector-space-isomorphic-to-n-th-product-o I'm trying to generalize what Zero is asking about here.

Answer (score 5):

First, pick a basis $\{w_i\}$ for $V$. Note that all elements of $V$ can be written as $\sum^n c_iw_i$ for some $c_i \in F$. This gives a natural function $f(\sum^n c_iw_i) = (c_1, ... c_n)$. Show that it is a bijection and that it is a homomorphism as far as $+$ is concerned.

Comment: (Of course, it is also a vector space isomorphism, i.e. multiplication with scalars is also respected)

Comment: @KarolisJuodele I don't know if you would be able to take a look, but I'm trying to generalize this to the case where instead of $n$ copies we are looking at the direct sum of copies of $F$ indexed by the basis of $V$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374069/generalization-of-n-th-dimensional-vector-space-isomorphic-to-n-th-product-o