# Generalization of $n$-th dimensional vector space isomorphic to $n$-th product of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, direct-sum, vector-space-isomorphism

This question is related to one asked by somebody else [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243612/n-dimensional-vector-space-isomorphic-to-the-n-th-product-of-a-field-as-abelian); however, unlike them, I do not want to show that a vector space over a field $F$ and of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to the $n$-th direct power $F^{n}$ of $F$. **Instead, I want to generalize this to the following case:**

> If $B$ is a basis for a vector space $V$ over $F$, I want to show that $V$ is isomorphic to the direct sum $\oplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ of copies of $F$ indexed  by $B$.

To that effect, I am hoping to come up with an isomorphic map from $V$ to $\oplus_{\alpha \in B}F$.

So, suppose $V$ is a vector space over $F$. Then, since every vector space has a basis, denote this basis by $B = \{ v_{i} \}_{i \in I}$, where $I$ is some indexing set.

Then, since every vector $w \in V$ can be uniquely represented as a linear combination of basis elements, we have that $w = \sum_{i \in I}x_{i}v_{i}$.

Now, this appears to give us a bijective map $\displaystyle g:V \to \oplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ defined by $\displaystyle w \mapsto \oplus_{i \in I}x_{i}$.

Is this the correct map and/or the correct way to denote it? It seems a little weird to me.

Also, I would need to show that such a map is a homomorphism. I'm not sure how I would write this:  I tried letting $w, \overline{w} \in V$ where $\displaystyle \overline{w} = \sum_{i \in I} \overline{x}_{i}\overline{v}_{i}$.

Then, $g(w) = \oplus_{i\in I}x_{i}$, $g(\overline{w}) = \oplus_{i \in I}\overline{x}_{i}$, but I'm not sure how to add these two direct sums together. In addition, does $g(w+\overline{w}) = \oplus_{i \in I} x_{i} + \overline{x}_{i}$? Or does it equal $\oplus_{i \in I} x_{i}\overline{x}_{i}$? I know that the direct sum is the cartesian product when all but finitely many of the summands are zero, but I am getting confused about what each side of this homomorphism should look like - if I am even getting the homomorphism itself correct, that is.

I thank you in advance for your help and patience!

Comment: Remember that an element in the vector space is always a finite(!) Linear combination  of the basis vectors. Therefore your map can hardly be an isomorphism.

Comment: @Verdruss ALannister is studying the direct sum, though. Am I misreading something?

Comment: @Verdruss what if I'm using the direct product instead of the direct sum?

Comment: @ALannister An infinite direct product of $F$ is not isomorphic to the infinite direct sum. Try computing the carnality of a basis. In particular, a basis for $\Pi_{b \in B} F$ is much bigger than $B$ when $B$ is infinite.

Comment: @AreaMan You're right, sorry. Forgot that the direct sum also works with finite support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ as a set consisting of finite support functions $B\rightarrow F$ as AreaMan says in (1.). Every vector in $V$ can be expressed as a **finite** linear combination of $B$, that is, if $w \in V, w \neq 0$, then $w = \sum_{i = 1}^m a_{s_i}v_{s_i}$ where $v_{s_i} \in B, a_{s_i} \in F, a_{s_i} \neq 0$ (I use $s_i$ as indexes, they are not necessarily the first $m$ vectors of $B$), then your function $g:V\rightarrow \bigoplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ maps $w$ to the function $f_w$ such that:
$$
f_w(x) = \begin{cases}
a_{s_i} & \text{if }  x = v_{s_i} \text{ for some $1\leq i\leq m$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
($f_w$ gives you the coefficients of $w$ when expressed as a linear combination of $B$, and $0 \mapsto f_0$ where $f_0(x) = 0$ for every $x$). You need to check:

1. $f_w \in \bigoplus_{\alpha \in B} F$ for every $w \in V$ (this happens since $B$ is a basis for $V$).
2. $g$ is well defined and bijective.
3. $g$ is a linear transformation.

In $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ sum and scalar multiplication is defined pointwise, that is, if $s,t \in \bigoplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ and $\lambda \in F$ then $s+t$ and $\lambda s$ lie in $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ and are defined as follows:
$$(s+t)(x) = s(x)+t(x)$$
$$(\lambda s)(x) = \lambda s(x)$$
for every $x \in B$ (operations on the right side are those of $F$).

The direct sum of vector spaces is a subspace of the direct product, that is: $$\bigoplus_{i \in I}V_i \leq \prod_{i \in I}V_i,$$ when $I$ is an infinite set the direct sum is a proper subspace, the sum and scalar multiplication is defined pointwise as above.

Comment: one question, though. How do I show that $g$ is well-defined?

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure what "$x$" is in the definition of $g$. I looked up what it means for a function to be well-defined, and what I think I'm supposed to show is that for $w,w^{\prime} \in V$ where $w = \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{s_{i}}v_{s_{i}}$, if $w = w^{\prime}$, then $g(w) = g(w^{\prime})$ But then, for $g(w) = f_{w}(x)$, how do I show that this equals $f_{w^{\prime}}(x) = g(w^{\prime})$? I think the problem is that I don't understand what $x$ is and what it has to do with how $g$ is defined.

Comment: also, shouldn't the operations $(s+t)(x) = s(x)+t(x)$ and $(\lambda s)(x) = \lambda s (x)$ actually be written as $(a_{s}+a_{t})(x) = a_{s}(x) + a_{t}(x)$ and $(\lambda a_{s})(x) = \lambda a_{s}(x)$ based on how you originally defined elements of $\oplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ in the range of $g$?

Comment: sorry for all the follow-up questions. I just want to make sure I understand this.

Comment: finally, the image of $w$ under $g$ is really the cartesian product of the $a_{s_{i}}$? And I'm thinking that the injectivity follows from the fact that since you are forbidding zero coefficients in the basis combinations that make up the vectors, in order for you to get $0$ as your image, the vector itself would have to be the zero vector?

Comment: $g$ is function that maps a vector to a function: $w \mapsto f_w$, where $f_w$ is defined as $f_w(x)=\ldots$ but $x$ is a variable (meaning an element of $B$ since $f_w$ is a function $B \rightarrow F$), it does not appear in the definition of $g$, is there to show how is $f_w$ definied. Showing $g(w) = g(w')$ is the same as $f_w = f_{w'}$, how do you prove two functions are equal?, you must show both have the same correspondence, that is, for every vector $x \in B$, $f_w(x) = f_{w'}(x)$.

Comment: why is the image under $g$ not a direct sum? Why is it just a coordinate?

Comment: Elements in $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in B}F$ are functions $B \rightarrow F$, so $s,t$ are just names, once you prove $g$ is an isomorphism they will be the image of some element in $V$, that is, $s = g(v) = f_v$ with $v \in V$ (and it will be unique), but not knowing this, $s$ and $t$ are just variable names I choose to describe the operations in the direct sum space.

Comment: The image of $g$ lie in the direct sum, think they are functions, they can be thought as "inifinite" tuples (finite support would mean finitely many non zero entries), but infinite direct products/sums are constructed using functions.

Comment: lastly, what I said about injectivity...also, it seems like surjectivity follows by construction but I don't know how to explain it in a way that isn't handwavey.

Comment: Surjectivity comes from the fact that elements on the direct sum are finite support functions, that is, if $f$ is an element lying in the direct sum, there is a finite subset of $B$, $A = \{v_{s_1}, \ldots, v_{s_m}\}$ for some $m$, such that $f(v_{s_i}) \neq 0$, then, what can you say about this vector $y = \sum_{i = 1}^m f(v_{s_i})v_{s_i}$? Can you show $g(y) = f$? Remember that $g(z)$ is the function giving you the coefficients of $z$ when expressed as a linear combination of $B$.

Comment: $g(y) = g(\sum_{i=1}^{m}f(v_{s_{i}})v_{s_{i}}) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}f(v_{s_{i}})$? Or is it $f(v_{s_{i}})$?

Comment: Assuming $g$ is linear, $g(y) = \sum_{i=1}^mf(v_{s_i})g(v_{s_i})$ where $g(v_{s_i})$ is a function (in the direct sum) such that $g(v_{s_i})(v_{s_i}) = 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I think the point is that I need to show that $g$ is linear. But, what I really don't understand here is why $g(v_{s_{i}})(v_{s_{i}}) = 1$ or $0$. Where is this $1$ coming from?!

Comment: Since $v_{s_i} \in B$, you can write $v_{s_i}$ as $1\cdot v_{s_i}$ (linear combination of $B$), also, $B$ is a basis, $v_{s_i}$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of $B \backslash \{v_{s_i}\}$, thus $g(v_{s_i})(x) = 0$ is $x \in B \backslash \{v_{s_i}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing seems more or less correct, but I notice some confusion about basic ( = fundamental, not trivial) things that hopefully this list of exercsies will help with. Please let me know what isn't clear.

1. The direct sum $\oplus_{b \in B} F$ can be thought of as functions $\phi : B \to F$ with the property that for all but finitely many $b$, $\phi(b) = 0$. These are added and scaled coordinatewise, like any other vector space of functions.

1b. The direct sum can also be thought of as the space of formal linear combinations of the elements in $B$. I.e. the space with vectors that are formal expressions (strings) that look like $2b_1 + 17b_2$, or in general a finite(!) sum $ a_0 b_0 + \ldots + a_n b_n$ for $a_i \in F$ and $b_i \in B$. These expressions are subject to certain identifications that make the space into a vector space, such as $(b + b') + b'' = b + (b' + b'')$, $b + b' = b' + b$ and $2b + b = 3b$.

Exercise: Prove that these two descriptions produce isomorphic spaces, by writing down a specific, natural isomorphism. You will have to work out a more precise definition of this second description. (If you want to, skip this and also the parenthetical comment in 3. I think that this point of view is helpful though, even if it is confusing at first. It also comes up a lot in algebra. You can google free vector space on a set to find better exposition on this.)

2. We will use the first description of the direct sum. Given a family of linear maps $T_b : F \to V$ for each $b \in B$, we obtain a map $T: \oplus_{b \in B} F \to V$, by sending a function $\phi : B \to F$ to $\Sigma_{b \in B} T_b(\phi(b))$. Note that only finitely many $\phi(b)$ are nonzero, hence this is a finite sum. Check that this is linear in $\phi$. Next check that, if $i_b : F \to \oplus_{b \in B} F$ is the map that sends $c$ to the function $\phi$ defined by [$\phi(b) = c$ and $\phi(b') = 0$ if $b \not = b'$], then $T \circ i_b = T_b$. (To learn more about this, search for coproducts of vector spaces. Aluffi's Algebra Chapter Zero presumably treats this somewhere - a very lucid book, I highly recommend it.) (Exercise: Phrase this in terms of the second description of direct sum.)
3. For each element $b \in B$ in a basis for $V$, we have a natural map $T_b : F \to V$ that sends $c$ to $cb$. Let $T$ be the map constructed from this data as in step $2$. (With the second perspective (1b) on the direct sum, $T$ is the map that takes a formal linear combination of basis vectors and evaluates it in $V$.)
4. This is the inverse to the map you define above. It is worthwhile to check that surjectivity corresponds to the condition that $B$ spanned, and injectivity corresponds to the linear independence of $B$.

Follow up exercise: We didn't really need to be working with $F$ in all of this. Figure out more general versions of these statements.

Comment: I'm a little confused - are you saying that proving these exercises are a necessary part of completing my solution? Otherwise, I was wondering if you could tell me whether the map I have provided is an isomorphism.

Comment: @ALannister see point 4. Yes it is an isomorphism, but if you are unsure how to add vectors in the direct sum, you should think about the first point my answer. Also, it's inverse is a very natural isomorphism (not a weird one), which the list of exercises will hopefully make more clear.

Comment: First, what is the relationship between the $b$ in $\phi(b)$ and the $\alpha \in B$ in point 1? Also, I'm still having trouble showing that the forward map is at least a homomorphism. What you have here is essentially showing that the map is a bijection, but showing it is a homormophism requires being able to work with sums, and what you have written here, in combination with what the other guy wrote in this answer has not helped explain it. For the function $g$ that he writes above, is the input an entire vector $w$? Then what is $x$? I'm still so confused...

Comment: @ALannister They are supposed to be the same index, $b$ runs in $B$. That was my mistake, I've edited. Do you understand why the set of complex valued functions on a set (such as the interval) forms a vector space? That this the primordial example.  I'd suggest looking at relevant sections in "Algebra Chapter 0" if you want more detailed explanation about these constructions (Though he works with modules, not vector spaces, if it makes a difference to you. I remember his exposition being very clear, and there are many good and simple exercises to help you understand the material.)